# cronR::cron_add() set for 3rd of every month(once every month scenario), but it also runs every Monday, is this a bug?

Tags: r, cron

When I run this cron_add() function, it shows `0 9 3 * 1` in the console, which means 'At 09:00 on day-of-month 3 and on Monday.' (I got this interpretation from [here](https://crontab.guru/#0_9_3_*_1)), but I want to run it once every month..am new to cronR so any help is appreciated, thank you!

`cron_add(frequency = "monthly", days_of_month = "third", at = "09:00")`

as a workaround, I have scheduled a cron job like this
cron_add(frequency = '0 9 3 * *') which interprets to [this](https://crontab.guru/#0_9_3_*_*): "At 09:00 on day-of-month 3". I will test this schedule and update.